# Twitter Typeahead differentiate between events

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-typeahead

I'm designing a system that allows users to annotate elements with either strings or terms from a vocabulary. I use Twitter typeahead for autocompletion and want to distinguish between an entered string and a term.

I am not able to figure out how to differentiate between the following situations:

1. a user pressing enter after coming up with its own value
2. a user pressing a down (or up) arrow (thereby selecting an autocompletion option) and pressing enter

The event listeners I wrote:

```
$("#itemInp").on('typeahead:select', function(event, term) {
    console.log("save: term", term);
});

$("#itemInp").on('keyup', function(event) {
    if(event.which == 13) {
        var string = $("#itemInp").val();
        console.log("save: string", string);
    }
});
```

With the following HTML:

```
<input id="itemInp"><input>
```

The first listener catches all selected typeahead terms, allowing for proper saving of the term. Problem is, the second listener is also triggered in case a user presses down and enter, selecting a typeahead term, which is now also saved as a plain string. Is there a way to not trigger the second listener in case a typeahead suggestion is selected?

A fiddle with the code loaded:
https://jsfiddle.net/zban3vs6/1/

Edit:
I considered a number of hacks, but all come with their own problems:

1. Add a special character to the string shown in input at the moment it is selected, by adding custom Typeahead display: https://jsfiddle.net/2t9rzhwf/
   This causes an additional character to be introduced, which is troublesome if a user presses the down arrow without pressing enter.
2. Attempt at sequencing the listeners, have the term listener trigger first, set a boolean to true, and filter on this boolean in the second listener. Don't like this way of filtering, since it introduces a delay.
3. The solution provided by @peter-clause, checking if the  selected value is in the list of available items.  But that way I can not keep track of whether the user intended to use the autocomplete option to select a term or explicitly is adding a plain string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem. This is how I solved it.

```
    var wasSelected = false;
    $("#itemInp").on('typeahead:select', function(event, term) {
        wasSelected = true;
        console.log("save: term", term);
    });

    $("#itemInp").on('change', function(event) {
        if(!wasSelected) {
            var string = $("#itemInp").val();
            console.log("save: string", string);
        }
        wasSelected = false;    
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, the main thing that helped me work around it was realising that the order of triggering the listeners does not change.My solution is more implementation specific, I clear the input field in the first listener when typeahead is used. If the second listener then encounters a field it assumes no input is provided for this case.

Answer (score 0):

A rather hacky solution, but you could check if the selected value is in the list of available items.

```
if (states.indexOf(string) == -1) {
    //...
}
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/zban3vs6/2/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this way I can not keep track of whether the user intended to use the autocomplete option to select a term or explicitly is adding a plain string.

I simplified the example, the application uses a typeahead which has linked uris, to disambiguate the selected terms. If someone for example types Alabama, without pressing up or down to select the typeahead suggestion, I would in this case save it as a term, while it should be save as a plain string.